# Eclipse paint.getColor() function returning incorrect values

Tags: java, android, eclipse

So I'm making a program with eclipse and I'm trying to make objects of only the same color collide. The problem is that when I compare two colors with paint.getColor or paint.getAlpha, it seems to think both colors are the same no matter what.

Here's some of the code:

```
private int red = -65536;
private int blue = -16776961;
private int green =  -16711936;
private int black = -16777216;

...

if( color == 0 ) paint.setColor( red );

else if( color == 1 ) paint.setColor( green );

else if( color  == 2 ) paint.setColor( blue );

else if(color == 3 ) paint.setColor( black );

...


if( x < (playerX + 35) && x > (playerX - 35))
{
    reset();
    if( paddle.getAlpha() == paint.getAlpha())
    {
        return 100;
    }
}
```

I assign the color the same way to paddle. Don't understand what the issue is.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your problem is that you got the constants incorrectly, try using the Color.RED, Color.BLUE, Color.GREEN, Color.BLACK, for your red,blue,green,and black variables respectively. Also comparing two alpha values doesn't mean that they are the same color, it only means that they have the same amount of transparency, what you have to do is to compare both alpha and actual RGB color of your paint against your paddle and then you can be sure that they are the same color.
Hope this helps.